# Standardizing/Normalizing Data with Z Scores from 1 to 10

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column array of z scores that I would like to convert to a 1-10 scale, with the lower z scores being closer to 10, and the higher z scores being closer to 1. Is this possible with excel?

Here is the array of z scores I have already calculated and expected Output (with terrible guesses as to what the outputs may be)

```
| Normalized ranking | Expected Output |
|--------------------|-----------------|
| 1.491945435        | 3               |
| -0.627194536       | 7               |
| -0.675220371       | 7.5             |
| 1.624016482        | 1.6             |
| -0.809292494       | 8               |
| 0.75526343         | 7.8             |
| -0.248991085       | 6               |
| 1.695001966        | 1.2             |
| 0.556314857        | 4.6             |
| 0.772197068        | 4.2             |
| -0.518007635       | 6.5             |
| -0.644338489       | 7.1             |
| 0.325256516        | 4.9             |
| -1.014251142       | 8               |
| -1.437203622       | 8.5             |
| -1.264350653       | 9.4             |
| 1.229381134        | 1               |
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just to clarify, the max z score does not necessarily have to be 1, nor does the lowest z score necessarily have to be 10.

Comment: Please include your expected output so we have a better reference on what you are after

Comment: So you're finding your `min` your `max` and scaling values between those values from 1 to 10?  what have you tried thusfar?

Comment: Added expect output picture. That is true, but the min and max don't necessarily have to be 1 and 10 respectively. Ideally a 10 would be -infinity and a 0 would be +infinity in terms of a z score if that makes sense. I am ashamed to say I haven't tried anything besides calculating the z scores to begin with, I am trying to make this clear for those that don't have an understanding of statistics, which is why I'm trying to convert to a 1-10 scale to begin with.

Comment: FYI posting a picture is better than no picture, however when working with this type of information, having the data as selectable text in your question goes a lot further as we can easily copy paste and convert it to numbers to work with.  having it as a picture can have multiple people retyping the numbers in your picture.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I apologize, when I copy from excel to stackoverflow, it automatically converts it to an image and uploads it to imgur. Very pain free for the submitter, not so much so for the people trying to help. How would you suggest I make it selectable text? Is there a way that I'm just missing?

Comment: See JvdV's edit.  Even if you have not formatted it correctly, that is something we can usually easily edit for you.  There is a link to a site that will format copy and paste information like the edit above.  I don't personally have the link, but I am sure @JvdV can provide a link.

Comment: I normally use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) tool.

Comment: That being said, the scores don't make sense with what you want. You said: "I would like to convert to a 1-10 scale, with the lower z scores being closer to 10, and the higher z scores being closer to 1", yet you gave `0.325256516` a 4.9 while `1.229381134` gets a 9 and an even higher z-score `1.491945435` recieves a 3. What would the formula be if you not using Excel?

Comment: Frankly I was just trying to make a table based on what I wanted because an expected output was asked for in the comments. I wasn't putting much thought into what the values would be, and I even made a mistake on the last entry, the expected output should be closer to a 1 or 2. To reiterate, a z score of say -10 should result in a 10 ranking (very far left of mean), and a z score of say 10 should result in a 1 ranking (very far right of mean). The lower the z score, the higher the value on a 1-10 scale, and the higher the z score, the lower the value on a 1-10 scale.

Answer (score 0):

After flipping the positive and negative signs on the range to avoid confusion, I used the following formula to convert on a scale from 1 to 10:

=1+(M24-MIN($M$24:$M$40))*(10-1)/(MAX($M$24:$M$40)-MIN($M$24:$M$40))

Unfortunately this left the lowest value as 1 and the highest value as 10, which was not exactly what I was looking for, but now my range looks good and it worked appropriately.